# Clarification on 彼のほかに私たち皆が行った

Tags: grammar, sentence

I am studying sentences with my colleagues and this was one of the sentences we picked for the week:

```
All of us went besides him.
かれのほかにわたしたちみながいった。
彼のほかに私たち皆が行った。
```

After I consulted with a native speaker, I was told that the sentence makes it sound like "everyone went", as in "he went and we all went as well". To have the meaning I originally wanted I have been told to use this instead:

```
かれいがいのわたしたちみながいった
```

But then, my colleagues asked another native speaker which said that the original sentence was OK.

I would kindly like to ask the community for some additional opinions.

Comment: Is there  reason you have おこなった in one version and いった in the other?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. That was a mistake we already corrected, but somehow ended up in my post. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`のほかに` means "besides" as in "in addition to"; `いがい` means "besides" as in "excepting". So the sentences with `のほかに` means "In addition to him, we went, too", while the one with `いがい` means "With the exception of him, we went".

Comment: A very clear explanation. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Zac R. Incidentally, if it is 彼以外にも私たち皆が行った, it is the same meaning as 彼のほかに私たち皆が行った.